# Vue JS do not show <p> if property is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this markup on my template:

```
<div class="locButton" v-for="location in locResult.slice(0, 4)">
  <h5>{{ location.legal_name }}</h5>
  <p>{{ location.address1 }}<p>
  <p v-if="location.address2 !== undefined">{{ location.address2 }}</p>
  <p>{{ location.pri_phone }}</p>
</div>
```

But as result the element still gets printed like this on the DOM:

```
<div class="locButton">
   <h5>Name</h5> 
   <p>Address1</p>
   <p></p><!----> 
   <p>Phone</p>
</div>
```

What should I do on the v-if in order to **not** output the html `<p>` tag at all if that property is undefined or empty?

Comment: have you tried <p v-if="location.address2">?

Comment: Hi @Laurens yes I did. It outputs the same thing.

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't print the <p> doing it like that...

Comment: Are you sure that `location.address2` is really undefined? Could it be, for example, a string with spaces, `" "`? I'd take a look in the developer tools to see what's actually in that property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a typo on your first `<p></p>` tag

```html
<div class="locButton" v-for="location in locResult.slice(0, 4)">
  <h5>{{ location.legal_name }}</h5>
  <p>{{ location.address1 }}<p> <-- THIS NEED TO BE </p>
  <p v-if="location.address2 !== undefined">{{ location.address2 }}</p>
  <p>{{ location.pri_phone }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh dear god, can't believe this :clap: :clap: :clap:

Comment: @TLJ Lol, nice. Apparently 4 people missed that one!

Comment: @Jaypee Maybe it's time to look into something like [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) (for VSCode). With this feature on, things like that should never happen again.

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
<p v-if="location.address2">{{ location.address2 }}</p>
```

EDIT:

proof that it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/ok2un1qj/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is very simple, you didn't close the `p` tag `<p>{{ location.address1 }}<p>`  therefore the brower closes the `p` tag of `location.address1` and opens an empty `<p></p>` then **Vue** renders `<!---->` because `location.address2` is not defined.
Another optimization that we can implement is here `<p v-if="location.address2 !== undefined">`. We don't need to compare `location.address2` with `undefined`. `v-if` will return true if `location.address2` is different of `null` or `undefiend`. Check the snippet below:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    location: {
      legal_name: 'Name',
      address1: 'Address1',
      pri_phone: 'Phone',
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h5>{{ location.legal_name }}</h5>
  <p>{{ location.address1 }}</p>
  <p v-if="location.address2">{{ location.address2 }}</p>
  <p>{{ location.pri_phone }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooooh, I think you're right. Nice catch! I didn't see the `<p>` instead of `</p>`.

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
<p v-if="location.address2 !== undefined">{{ location.address2 }}</p>
```

to

```
<p v-if="location.address2">{{ location.address2 }}</p>
```

Comment: It outputs the same as shown in my question `<p></p><!---->`, I've tried that as well.

Comment: could may be because I'm using vue's dev library? I'll try with production library

Comment: Nope, tried with production library but same thing happens =(

Comment: @Jaypee Put a JSfiddle or CodePen up demonstrating this, please.

Comment: @ceejayoz ok I'm calling an API so I have to build a JSON I'll prepare it and post

Answer (score 0):

Solutions proposed by the other posts should invariably work, but another option is to use [double logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Double_NOT_(!!)) in series to explicitly force the conversion of any value to the corresponding **boolean** primitive.

```
!!location.address2 // Enforces boolean value -> True if it contains a value, false otherwise
```

### Demo

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      location: {
        address1: 'Some address',
        address2: undefined
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addAddress2() {
      this.location.address2 = 'Address 2';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app>p {
  background-color: lavender;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ location.address1 }}</p>
  <p v-if="!!location.address2">{{ location.address2 }}</p>

  <button @click="addAddress2">Add address 2</button>
</div>
```